# How to use Unicode from Delphi in C++ DLL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can I use a Unicode PWideChar in Delphi to call a C++ function in a DLL? I want to send a string from Delphi to C++ and modify it.

```
function Test(a: PWideChar): Integer; cdecl; external 'c:\Win32Project1.dll' name 'Test';

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Test(char* a)
{
    a = "汉语";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to define more clearly the goal. You want to pass a string from the DLL back to the caller? Who is going to allocate the string? Or are you only ever going to return literals? What encoding do you want to use?  Given that you seem a little lacking in experience in this field, would you consider using BSTR?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes essentially. I can return the string from C++ to Delphi but the other way round is too hard. I would like to use UTF16.

Comment: I don't really understand that comment. Yes essentially what?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just want to send a string from Delphi to C++ and modify it. With for example a `replace` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the caller allocates a buffer which is passed to the callee, along with the buffer length. The callee then populates the buffer.

```cpp
size_t Test(wchar_t* buff, const size_t len)
{
    const std::wstring str = ...;
    if (buff != nullptr)
        wcsncpy(buff, str.c_str(), len);
    return str.size()+1; // the length required to copy the string
}
```

On the Delphi side you would call it like this:

```
function Test(buff: PWideChar; len: size_t): size_t; cdecl; external "mydll.dll";
....
var
  buff: array [0..255] of WideChar;
  s: string;
....
Test(buff, Length(buff));
s := buff;
```

If you don't want to allocate a fixed length buffer, then you call the function to find out how large a buffer is needed:

```
var 
  s: string;
  len: size_t;
....
len := Test(nil, 0);
SetLength(s, len-1);
Test(PWideChar(s), len);
```

If you wish to pass a value to the function, I suggest that you do that through a different parameter. That makes it more convenient to call, and does not force you to make sure that the input string has a buffer large enough to admit the output string. Maybe like this:

```
size_t Test(const wchar_t* input, wchar_t* output, const size_t outlen)
{
    const std::wstring inputStr = input;
    const std::wstring outputStr = foo(inputStr);
    if (buff != nullptr)
        wcsncpy(buff, outputStr.c_str(), len);
    return outputStr.size()+1; // the length required to copy the string
}
```

On the other side it would be;

```
function Test(input, output: PWideChar; outlen: size_t): size_t; cdecl; 
  external "mydll.dll";
```

And the calling code should be obvious.

Comment: Will there be degrade in performance if PWideChar conversions are used  in a loop? example: `PWideChar('some jolly string')`;

Comment: The compiler converts that so there is no perf impact. Perf questions are impossible to answer without some baseline. Obviously encoding takes more than zero time. But do you want your program to be fast or correct?