# How to pass UTF-8 string from Delphi to a DLL C extern function?

Tags: c, string, delphi, utf-8

I am calling from Delphi a C extern function in a Visual Studio compiled DLL.  The DLL method in turn calls a C++ method that takes as argument a C++ string type. The string at the Delphi end is UTF-8 encoded (without the BOM). I need to make sure the C++ method that takes the string type gets the UTF-8 encoded string.

I can modify the DLL source code. My question:

My UTF-8 string on the Delphi side is of type string. What type should the C extern method take? PChar, PWideChar? and how do I convert that to a C++ string type?

Note: I can't convert the UTF-8 string into an AnsiString first because the encoding stores some Greek letters that must be preserved. The C++ end will make a copy of the Delphi string and handle the disposal of any allocated memory.

Delphi end (Using XE6):

```
mystr : string;

callCExternMethod (mystr) // cast to what?
```

C++ End (Using VS 2013):

```
void callCExternMethod (????? mystr) {

  // convert mystr to C++ string type

  callCPlusPlusMethod (takes C++ string type)
}
```

Comment: Surely this question has been asked 100's of times already..... have you tried googling? Every time you call a Windows function that uses text you're doing this very thing.

Comment: PAnsiChar on the Delphi side. const char* on the C++ side. You need to encode as a null terminated utf8 strong before calling the function through. The RTL has functions for that. Try searching.

Comment: Compulsory reading: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/UTF-8_Conversion_Routines you are looking for Utf8Encode http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.UTF8Encode

Comment: Oh and make sure to get the calling convention correct. It needs to be either `cdecl` or `stdcall` (probably the former).

Comment: I've spent the last hour and a half investigating this, stackoverflow is my last resort, I never use stackoverflow without doing due diligence, including searching stackoverflow itself. Obviously one can miss things when researching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Delphi side the parameter is `PAnsiChar` which you pass like this: `PAnsiChar(Utf8String(str))`.

On the C++ side you receive the parameter as `const char*`.

Obviously you need to ensure that the calling convention matches.

Comment: That worked. I thank you for the answer. Knowing the answer I can now see there are similar responses eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867113/how-to-use-unicode-from-delphi-in-c-dll which for some reason didn't show up in my search. I apologize for using up the responder's time unnecessarily. Please delete the question is it deemed superfluous.

Comment: In Delphi 2009+, `UTF8Encode()` is deprecated, use `UTF8String` instead: `PAnsiChar(UTF8String(str))`, or just declare `str` as `UTF8String` to begin with, then type-cast it as-is: `PAnsiChar(str)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau UTF8String was prohibited in "nex gen" Delphi for LLVM

Comment: @Arioch'The: [`UTF8String` and `RawByteString()` have been re-enabled for mobile platforms in Delphi 10.1 Berlin](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/What%27s_New#Other_RTL_Changes).  If you don't want to rely on `UTF8String`, then you can use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so they finally decided to stop pi.. spitting against the wind? I am surprised :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `UTF8String` type:

```
mystr : string;
u8: UTF8String;

u8 := UTF8String(mystr);
callCExternMethod(PAnsiChar(u8));
```

Note: the `UTF8String` type is not available for use on mobile platforms in Delphi XE5 through 10.0 Seattle, unless you use a patch to enable it:

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/10/the-return-of-the-byte-strings/

`UTF8String` has been re-enabled for use in mobile starting in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: You need an explicit type-cast to avoid a "*W1057 Implicit string cast from 'string' to 'UTF8String'*" warning: `u8 := UTF8String(mystr);`

Comment: Personally I'd better disable that specific warning. In the case of explicit typecast though there would be no need with temporary variable.

Comment: I would not disable the warning. *Implicit* string casts *may* modify data, which is why a warning even exists at all. An *explicit* cast tells the compiler that you understand and accept the risk. The warning happens on every implicit assignment of one string type to a different string type. If the target string type is an Ansi string, you get a slightly different warning: `W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'`.